# Problem with Promise.allSettled. Unexpected returns

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

That's my code:

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");

const getRandomDelay = maxDelay => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * maxDelay) * 1000;
};

const getAsyncNumbers = () => {
  const successDelay = getRandomDelay(1);
  const errorDelay = getRandomDelay(3);  

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve([1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2]), successDelay);

    setTimeout(() => reject(new Error("No numbers found :(")), errorDelay);
  });
};

Promise.allSettled([getAsyncNumbers(), getAsyncNumbers(), getAsyncNumbers()])
  .then(results => {
    results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status))
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(`${err} Proces zakończony!`);
  });
```

I expected that console returns something like fulfilled or rejected but I received:
undefined
undefined
undefined

...

I checked what results is and I received:

PromiseInspection {
  _bitField: 33554432,
  _settledValueField: [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 ] }
PromiseInspection {
  _bitField: 33554432,
  _settledValueField: [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 ] }
PromiseInspection {
  _bitField: 33554432,
  _settledValueField: [ 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2 ] }

Maybe there is someone here who can help me? Thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same issue. I traced it to the latest version of Bluebird (as of the time I'm writing this) included with Webpack which is handling the transpilation. At first, I wrote a wrapper to finish translating the values to what was expected:

```
const IS_FULFILLED = 0x2000000
const IS_REJECTED = 0x1000000
const STATUS_MAP = {
  [IS_FULFILLED]: { status: 'fulfilled' },
  [IS_REJECTED]: { status: 'rejected' },
}

const transformAllSettled = (results) =>
 results.map(({ _bitField, _settledValueField, ...rest }) =>
    _bitField ? { ...STATUS_MAP[_bitField], value: _settledValueField } : rest,
  )

...

return Promise.allSettled(myPromises).then(transformAllSettled)
```

This has the benefit of passing through the response if in the future the issue is resolved. Though, I eventually settled for logic that doesn't rely on a feature that is still in a draft version of ECMAScript.

```
const gracefulFail = (promise) => promise.catch((error) => ({ error }))
const withoutRejected = (responses) => responses.filter(item => !item.error)

return Promise.all(myPromises.map(gracefulFail)).then(withoutRejected)
```

This will allow for all the promises to resolve without one or more rejections failing the whole set, returning the responses only for those that were not rejected. Of course, you could handle the rejections in whatever way you pleased.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but I just ran into the same issue.

As [@nando-pena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13521354/nando-pena) said, the responsable for this "change" is, also in my case, Bluebird.

What I found is that in our case, the array returned by `Promise.allSettled()` has elements of type `PromiseInspection`.

```
interface PromiseInspection {
    any reason()
    any value()
    boolean isPending()
    boolean isRejected()
    boolean isFulfilled()
    boolean isCancelled()
}
```

So you can access the status/result of each promise using the interface definition.